# Elementor header not working in only one mobile page

Tags: wordpress, header, responsive, elementor, hamburger-menu

last resource after lots of reading elsewhere and browsing other people's questions...
The elementor header on our site is working fine in all pages and devices except on mobile for the last page created: https://thecvcollective.com/community-hub/
When clicking the hamburger menu nothing happens. All other pages work fine.
Any suggestions please? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have created different menus for different pages,
so for community-hub pages there are some setting missing for mobile, and for that
.hfe-dropdown is not there in this page,
copy other menu style and paste it to community menu and it will work.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately, I have tried that already, even now I did: 1. removed completely the menu and pasted the one from our homepage (didn't work) 2. added a new hfe element with the header menu selected (didn't work). I also pushed live another new page (join us) and works fine. I think the problem on that community-hub page is the embedded trello board iframe